# How to update a table with composite key using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am newbie to hibernate. If there is a table which has a composite key, how to update the table using hibernate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a [`composite-id`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid) for that.

Example copied from the link:

```
<composite-id
    name="propertyName"
    class="ClassName"
    mapped="true|false"
    access="field|property|ClassName">
    node="element-name|."

    <key-property name="propertyName" type="typename" column="column_name"/>
    <key-many-to-one name="propertyName" class="ClassName" column="column_name"/>
    ......
</composite-id>
```

---

You can then retrieve the record using [`load`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#load(java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable)) instead of `get`

```
Book bk1 = new Book();
bk1.setBookId(1);
bk1.setBookName("Hibernate Examples");
bk1.setAuthor("ISHTEK");
Book bk2 = (Book) session.load(Book.class, bk1);
```

which you can then [update](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#update(java.lang.Object)) after changing your values

```
session.update(bk1);
```

Comment: i have made this change in xml file, my doubt is like in the java code we will be getting the persistant object using the hibernate session, right . So in the get method we will be passing the class and the attribut, currently i have to check for two attribute before updating that record. how is that possible..

Comment: @Hari: Please check my updated answer, hope I got your question right.